# keycloak behind an ALB ingress doesn't load admin panel or static resources

Tags: keycloak, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm trying to install Bitnami Keycloak helm chart (14.1.0) on EKS served behind ALB ingress. Helm values is pretty straightforward [Load balancer controller + external dns is installed and configured properly]:

```
auth:
  adminUser: admin
  adminPassword: "123456

production: true
proxy: edge

postgresql:
  enabled: true
  auth:
    postgresPassword: "123456"
    password: "123456"

cache:
  enabled: false

service:
  type: LoadBalancer

ingress:
  enabled: true
  servicePort: http
  ingressClassName: alb
  hostname: 'keycloak.XXX.XXX'
  path: '/'
  pathType: Prefix
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ip-address-type: ipv4
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: 'routing.http.drop_invalid_header_fields.enabled=true'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: http
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/inbound-cidrs: 0.0.0.0/0
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:XXXXXXXXXXX
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: "keycloak.XXX.XXX"
```

Homepage of keycloak is loading but without images. Also going to admin console returns 404.

[image]

**[UPDATE]**

1. Switching service type to `NodePort` and `target-type: instance` doesn't make any difference.